# running a trained keras model in c++

Tags: python, c++, keras

I have trained a multi layer perceptron in keras, serialized the model to JSON and saved the weights to HDF5. How can I import this model in C/C++ to do some prediction with it ?

Comment: What are the layers used in your model ?

Answer (score 2):

[frugally-deep](https://github.com/Dobiasd/frugally-deep) seems to have the most functionality in terms of running Keras models in C++. It supports several more model architectures than keras2cpp.

Answer (score 1):

This should do excactly what you want.

Usage

Save your network weights and architecture.

Dump network structure to plain text file with dump_to_simple_cpp.py script.

Use network with code from keras_model.h and keras_model.cc

See the github for more information as linked below.

[keras2cpp](https://github.com/pplonski/keras2cpp)

Answer (score 1):

Two steps -

1. Save Keras model into text files in python
2. In C++/C, read those text files, and run the model in a multithreading environment.

**Above Steps in detail**

1. For first step, call save_keras_model_as_text from keras2cpp.py on [Github](https://github.com/upashu1/keras2cpp_multithreading_image_segmentation)-

   save_keras_model_as_text(model, open('/content/modeltext.txt', 'w') )

   save_keras_model_as_text(model, open('/content/modellayersonlytext.txt', 'w') , noweight=True)
2. In c++/c projects, include [keras.h /keras.cpp](https://github.com/upashu1/keras2cpp_multithreading_image_segmentation) files.
3. convert input image into Keras format or read input image into Keras format from a file.

'''

```
//assume dst is pointer to an image object. This 
//can be of CxImage / CImg /OpenCV or of any other 
//library.

int h = dst->GetHeight();
int w= dst->GetWidth();;
    
int *img = new int[h*w*3];
int *img_r = img, *img_g =&img[h*w], *img_b=&img[2*h*w];
   
    
    for (int y = 0; y < h; y++) {
        for (int x = 0; x < w;x++) {
             RGBQUAD rgb= dst->GetPixelColor(x,y);
             *img_r= rgb.rgbRed; img_r++;
             *img_g= rgb.rgbGreen; img_g++; 
             *img_b = rgb.rgbBlue; img_b++;
            
          }
         
       }
```

'''

4. Call [ExecuteKerasSegmentation](https://github.com/upashu1/keras2cpp_multithreading_image_segmentation).

   '''

   ```
    //text files in which keras model is saved.
    char *modelfile ="modellayersonlytext.txt";  
    char *weightfile="modeltext.txt";

    int *result = ExecuteKerasSegmentation(img, h, w, 3, modelfile, weightfile);
   ```

   '''
5. result contains the segmentation result. You may save it into pgm file or convert it into your image library object and use it further.

'''

```
save_image_pgm("segmentation_map.pgm",result,h,w,127); //127 is scaling factor for binary images.
```

'''